# Having Error installing GridDB on my system?

Tags: griddb

I am trying to install GridDB on my system and getting this error

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:griddb/griddb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install griddb
```

E: Unable to locate package griddb

I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the GridDB repository and package list, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following installation steps:
https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/using-apt/#install-with-apt-get

You need to add the repo first:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://www.griddb.net/apt griddb/5.1 multiverse" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/griddb.list'
$ wget -qO - https://www.griddb.net/apt/griddb.asc | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install griddb-meta
```